# How to receive texts in Ubuntu desktop

Tags: android, pidgin, google, google-talk

I would like to **receive and send texts** on Ubuntu desktop.

I would be preferable to receive them via **pidgin**, and also when my phone is not present. I do **not have bluetooth.** It is a **google voice** number, and I have an **android device.** I also do not want to pay for an app or something.

Note: Most solutions on the web are **broken** and **out of date.** At least check if it is more recent than a Google policy change.